# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - behavior of Single click Unsubscribe in Email Header

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscribe

I have a question about the Single Click Unsubscribe link that Marketing Cloud adds to the Email header and is rendered accordingly in the Email (Gmail, Yahoo etc.)

What is the exact behavior of the Unsubscribe link? Traditionally our Unsubscribe link at the bottom of the Email navigates the user to a page where once confirmed, the subscriber is unsubscribed from the publication list linked to that Email.

Is the behavior of the Single Click Unsubscribe in the Email header the same - is the user automatically unsubscribed by marketing cloud from the associated publication list? Or is this a business unit level unsubscribing for a Multi-Org setup or an unsubscribe from All Subscribers?

Thank you for any help.

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities in the mail header that wraps your emails.

The ESP decides which one they use:

- The mailto variant of the link sends an email to the reply mail management infrastructure.

`<mailto:leave-xxxx-yyyyy-zzz-aaa-bb@leave.mail.yourDomain.com>`  which contains encrypted information about the recipient, the job etc (what I masked as xxx yyy etc)

- The http variant technically leverages the subscription center infrastructure without displaying it (which makes it "one click"). It acts as if a user went there and unsubscribed from all.

`https://click.mail.yourDomain.com/subscription_center.aspx?jwt=eyJhbGcxxxxxxxkpXVCJ9.eyJtaWQiOiI1MTAwMDMwMjQiLCJzIjoiODk1MDg0NjIiLCJsaWQiOiI0NTIiLCJqIjoiNDM4MDY3IiwiaxxxxxxxI1MDAwMTQifQ.f9tFsFELVxTWoWXKIw3oyvfULxxxxxxM11c`

`List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click`

**Inside SFMC, both result in a LogUnsubEvent.**

LogUnsubEvent works as documented.

It is handled as defined in your Business Units settings (for all BUs / from this BU only) and records an event in the _Unsubscribe Data View.

In case of "from this BU only", additionally a record is added to the _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes Data view. This does not happen if setting is "for all BUs".

This Data View is special as it does not record events like the "classic" DVs _Unsubscribe, _Sent etc., but statuses. Meaning that if the Unsub is removed again, the record *vanishes*.

The statuses in the _Unsubscribe Data Views are *aggregated* to what you see on All Subscribers List.

_Unsubscribe Data Views are BU specific.
In case of "from this BU only", All Subscribers List aggregates a different result depending on *where you are logged in and open it*.

==

What happens on the frontend is managed by the ESP.
Typically, you'd just stay where you are (the inbox). No redirect etc.